# Model parallelism not working? All GPUs not being used?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, parallel-processing, keras, computer-vision

I have been stuck with a problem like this for a while now. I have an AWS setup with 500 GB of ram and about 7 GPUs. Now the issue is that each time I try to run my keras with tensorflow as back-end code, it runs out of memory. I have found out the reason for this as well. The reason is that each you GPU just has 12gb of memory whereas my model needs more than that. So, how can I run the model such that it uses the memory of all the GPUs combined to load the model and not just rely on the memory of one GPU for loading the entire model and running out of memory? I have tried model parallelism with keras and it seems to be set-up correctly as on printing the layers , each layer is assigned to the programmed GPU but the model is still trying to load into a single GPU's memory I.e. just 11gb and soon runs out of memory.

Any idea what's going on?

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    x = conv2d_bn(img_input, 32, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')
    x = conv2d_bn(x, 32, 3, 3, padding='valid')
    x = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 3, 3)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = conv2d_bn(x, 80, 1, 1, padding='valid')
    x = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 3, 3, padding='valid')
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    # mixed 0, 1, 2: 35 x 35 x 256
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 32, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed0')
    print(x)

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    # mixed 1: 35 x 35 x 256
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed1')

    # mixed 2: 35 x 35 x 256
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed2')
    print(x)
```

Edit: 
[Here's the link to the code](https://pastebin.com/bcBMwp9X) . Also it may be noted that currently, I am just feeding one image to the model so as to test whether my GPU can handle it. Hence, reducing the batch size is not a possible solution.

Comment: No, we do not have any idea unless you provide a better problem description, like actual model code. When you get out of memory issues, the first thing to do is to reduce batch size.

Comment: Updated the op with the code. As of now, I am just giving the model one image.

Comment: put the the first convolution and data loading on cpu and the rest of the model on one gpu otherwise they won't be able to share gradients

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan You mean something like https://pastebin.com/dVGeZLJS ?

Comment: exactly...and the dataloading process, the function that calls for input should be under with devices('cpu')

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Thanks, however, I am unable to understand as to what you mean by dataloading process cause afaik ,that's done by the keras.fit_generator right?

Comment: @Reuben_v1 i think you are right...i missed the point that its keras...i think in this case the generator is the problem..have you reduced the size of the batch? to see where it start overloading gpu memory?

Comment: Yes , I am currently not using any batches. Only one image is being given to the model. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174399/discussion-between-reuben-v1-and-eliethesaiyan).

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Unfotunately what you suggested doesn't do the trick for me. Actually I somehow need a way by which tensorflow uses all the GPUs along with their memory for storing my model. Unfortunately, currently when I get the resource exhausted error, I am shown around 11gb is memory limit which means tensorflow is only assigning it to the memory of 1 GPU whereas I have 8 in total

Comment: if i am not mistaken, i think it might not be possible to combine all gpu memories...in the cases i have seem,a copy of each batch is given to all gpus and they all do their forward and average the results on two one main gpu..i am not sure if keras accepts tf.records as inputs..if you could manage to use tf records then you could control your batches instead of letting your generator handling it for you.IMO the generator is the one that is using much memory

Comment: Model parallelism is aimed at doing just that but in my case, that does not seem to help